# How to enable xamarin.ide.insight?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I can't open xamarin.iOS or xamarin.android. Please see the attachment.

It says the required addin xamarin.ide.insights is disabled.  How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you can't open the xamarin? Have you tried to reinstall the visual studio?